# Yearly comparison timeseries ggplot2 R

Tags: r, performance, ggplot2, line, time-series

My df:

```
> head(merged)
        Date patch     prod workmix_pct jobcounts travel FWIHweeklyAvg              month year
1 2013-03-29  BVG1 2.932208         100      9480   30.7      1.627024              March 2013
2 2013-03-29 BVG11 2.769156          10       968   34.3      4.475714              March 2013
3 2013-03-29 BVG12 2.857344          16      1551   33.8      3.098571              March 2013
4 2013-03-29 BVG13 2.870111          13      1267   29.1      1.361429              March 2013
5 2013-03-29 BVG14 3.011260          17      1625   28.1      1.550000              March 2013
6 2013-03-29 BVG15 3.236246          21      1946   24.9      1.392857              March 2013
```

I am trying to plot year on year comparison of `prod` column. I have data from `March 2013` till `March 2015`.

This is what I have tried:

```
ggplot(data=merged,aes(Date, prod)) + #dataframe 
  geom_line(data=merged[merged$patch %in% c("BVG1"),],aes(y=prod, colour="red"),lwd = 1.3,)+ #select BVG1
  geom_smooth() +
        scale_x_date(labels = date_format("%b-%Y"),breaks = "1 month") + #how many breaks and Date format
        ylab("Actual Prod") +
        ggtitle("Scotland's Overall Performance Financial Year\n2013/14 Vs 2014/15") +
        theme(axis.title.y = element_text(size = 25, vjust=0.3,face = "bold",color = "red"), 
        axis.text.y=element_text(size=25, color="blue"),
        plot.title = element_text(lineheight = .8,face = "bold",color = "red",size = 45, vjust = 1),
        legend.text = element_text(size=35))+ theme(legend.position="none")
```

which gives me this plot:

[image]

Now I want to plot 2013 Vs 2014 and then 2014 Vs 2015. and lastly 2013 Vs 2015.

This is what I have tried:

```
ggplot(data=merged,aes(Date)) + #dataframe 
  geom_line(data=merged[merged$year==2013,],aes(y=prod, colour="red"),lwd = 1.3,)+ #select 2013
  geom_line(data=merged[merged$year==2014,],aes(y=prod, colour="blue"),lwd = 1.3,)+ #select 2014
        scale_x_date(labels = date_format("%b-%Y"),breaks = "1 month") + #how many breaks and Date format
        ylab("Actual Prod") +
        ggtitle("Scotland's Overall Performance Financial Year\n2013/14 Vs 2014/15") +
        theme(axis.title.y = element_text(size = 25, vjust=0.3,face = "bold",color = "red"), 
        axis.text.y=element_text(size=25, color="blue"),
        plot.title = element_text(lineheight = .8,face = "bold",color = "red",size = 45, vjust = 1),
        legend.text = element_text(size=35))+ theme(legend.position="none")
```

This is what I am getting[image]:

Would be nice to have something like below:

[image]

And:

[image]

but NOT in a `weekly` view but a `monthly` View.

Any help or ideas would be appreciated.

Many thanks

**UPDATE**

As per Ruthger Righart Answer. I did the following:

```
library(dplyr)

mergedYearonYearProdMeans = merged %>%
                                group_by(year,month) %>%
                                mutate(MonthlyAve = mean(prod))
ordered.months <- factor(mergedYearonYearProdMeans$month, as.character(mergedYearonYearProdMeans$month))

ggplot(data=mergedYearonYearProdMeans,aes(ordered.months,MonthlyAve,group=year,shape=year,color=year)) + #dataframe 
  geom_line()+ 
  scale_color_manual(values = c("red","blue","green"))
```

My Graph doesn't start from month January + 2015 Prod should only be for Months Jan, Feb and March and shouldnt show a flat green line for other months as shown below.

[image]

Comment: You have month and year in your data, so why not as a next step re-calculate the mean Prod value as a function of month and year and then make a new ggplot using aes(month)?

Comment: Not sure how to do it. any example code would be appreciated

Comment: Hi Shery, I created an example that shows how to make such a plot. Hope this helps!

Comment: This is great... didn't think I had to summarise data per month per year...Resoved my issue...thank you @RuthgerRighart

Comment: @RuthgerRighart Sorry, my graph doesn't start from January and There shouldn't be any values for other months in 2015. (Please see the update above). Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Often the preparation of the data is most important for these kind of plots.
Seeing your data I guess you need to compute the average "prod" value as a function of year and month. This step can be performed using plyr package using the ddply function. A simple data example to see how this works:

```
library(plyr)

dat<-data.frame(year=c("2012","2012","2012", "2012","2012","2012"), month=c("Jan", "Jan", "Jan", "Feb", "Feb", "Feb"), prod=as.numeric(c("2.00", "1.00", "3.00", "0.50", "1.50", "2.00")))

newdat<-ddply(dat, .(year, month), summarize, prod = mean(prod))
```

After this step your data should have one average "prod" value for every year and month in newdat and is in the right format so it can be plotted using ggplot. I created a new simplified data example which has the same formatting:

```
df<-data.frame(year=c("2012","2012","2012","2012","2013","2013","2013","2013"), month=c("Jan","Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec", "Jan","Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"), prod=c("0.33","0.24","0.36","0.22","0.31","0.28","0.39","0.25", "0.23","0.22","0.46","0.52","0.61","0.18","0.59","0.55", "0.13","0.14","0.56","0.42","0.41","0.48","0.59","0.65"))
```

A vector should be made to get right ranking of months in x-axis (otherwise ggplot orders the months in alphabetical order)

```
ordmonth<- factor(df$month, as.character(df$month))

library(ggplot2)

p<-ggplot(data=df, aes(x=ordmonth, y=prod, group=year, shape=year, color=year))+geom_line()
p<-p+scale_color_manual(values = c("red", "blue"))
```

[image]